# Left body and sidebar width issue on explorer

Tags: html, css, width

I'm fighting this error and i can't find a way of fixing it...

Take a look at this: http://www.28deseptiembre.com/riverplate/

Sidebar it's going under... i dunno why, i've tryied all combination of tricks that i know without success...

On pages sidebar it's fine... http://www.28deseptiembre.com/riverplate/quienes-somos so problem it's only on index

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your css to:

```
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

And I noticed that you have overflow:auto; on:

```
#cuerpo {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I recomend removing it because that causes the problem you see as well